# javascript cell selection

Tags: javascript, selection, cell

I want to select a cell range in an HTML table and using Javascript to change the background color of the selected cells. Is there an event to get all ids of the selected cells?

---

I tried this code:

```
function getSelectedCells()
{
   selObj = window.getSelection();
   alert(selObj);
}
```

And it printed out the cell content of the selected cells. Does anyone know how i can use this to get the id of the selected cells?

Comment: You mean select with the mouse or something?  Exactly what sort of user interaction are you thinking about?

Comment: Yes. For example select the first 5 cells in the first row. I have a default string value in the cells. This string is then highlighted. Then I want to click a button which would trigger the function to change the background color of the selected cells.

Comment: I tried this code:

function getSelectedCells()
{
   selObj = window.getSelection();
   alert(selObj);
}

And it printed out the cell content of the selected cells. Does anyone know how i can use this to get the id of the selected cells?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will try your approach. I found a solution myself but it is far from pretty and only because I know how the ids of the cells are structured. Here is the code but it only works sometimes. I guess the regular expression is a little buggy. I use this to avoid changing the background from the wrong cells:

```
function foo() 
{  
    selecIds = new Array();

    sel = window.getSelection();

    firstPosSelA = sel.anchorNode;
    lastPosSelF = sel.focusNode;

    firstCellId = firstPosSelA.parentNode.getAttribute("id");
    lastCellId = lastPosSelF.parentNode.getAttribute("id");

    startSelNumInd = firstCellId.indexOf("wc");
    endSelNumInd = lastCellId.indexOf("wc");

    startSelNum = firstCellId.substring(startSelNumInd + 2);
    endSelNum = lastCellId.substring(endSelNumInd + 2);
    firstSelecRow = firstCellId.substring(0, startSelNumInd + 2);

    for ( i = startSelNum; i <= endSelNum; i++)
    {
        cellid = firstSelecRow + i;
        selecIds.push(cellid); 
    }

    alert(selecIds);

    for ( eachSelCell in selecIds)
    {
        currentElement = document.getElementById(selecIds[eachSelCell]);
        backColor = currentElement.style.backgroundColor;

        if (backColor !='' || backColor!='#C0C0C0' || backColor!='#c0c0c0' || backColor!='rgb(192, 192, 192)' || backColor!='RGB(192, 192, 192)')
        {
            if (/\d\w/.test(selecIds[eachSelCell]) || (/fc/.test(selecIds[eachSelCell])))
            {
            }   
            else
            {
                changeBackgroundColor(selecIds[eachSelCell]);
            }   
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I would say if you know the structure of the ids then using that knowledge in your design would be more appropriate. The machine gun approach I suggested is only for scenarios where you only know the type of element range you are selecting (or for instances where there is no id).

Answer (score 0):

I set up a test for solving this using jQuery because honestly it just makes it easier. The method I used was to iterate over the possible items and check if they are inside the range.

```
function display() {
  if (document.getSelection) {
    var str = document.getSelection();
  } else if (document.selection && document.selection.createRange) {
    var range = document.selection.createRange();
    var str = range;
  } else {
    var str = 0;
  }
  if(str != 0){
  $("td").each(function() {
    var range, sourceRange, compare;
    range = str.getRangeAt(0);
    sourceRange = document.createRange();
    sourceRange.selectNode(this);
    compare = range.compareBoundaryPoints(Range.START_TO_END, sourceRange) * range.compareBoundaryPoints(Range.END_TO_START, sourceRange);
    if (compare == -1){
            alert(this.id);
    }
    /*
    if you really just want to change the background color, uncomment this code:
    */
    /*
    if (compare == -1){
            $(this).css("background", "#f00");// or any other color here.
    }
    */
  });
  );
}

if (window.Event)
  document.captureEvents(Event.MOUSEUP);
document.onmouseup = display;
```

this likely isn't the best solution but it might get us moving in the right direction.

Comment: I tried it and firebug sent the message $("td") is not defined

Comment: After including jquery 1.4.2 I get now the message str.getRangeAt(0) is not a function.